# Any limitation for having many files in a directory in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems

I have 100,000+ files in a directory in my MacOS X and looks it is slow for my script to read a file in them.

Is there any limitation or recommendation to have that many files? Should I split them to some directories?

The limitation I found was that I can't `mv * foo` for all 100,000 files. It shows an error, saying "too long argument." It works with approximately less than 20,000 files.

Comment: Currently I have 380,000 files in a directory and realize that even opening a file simply takes 10+ seconds. I have decided to separate them to some directories.

Comment: The HFS+ file system should be able to store and access large numbers of files in a directory by their full name without too much trouble. But you need to watch out with wildcards. When you use `*` or `?` as part of an argument to a command, the operating system searches the whole directory for matching files (slow), and then it replaces your argument with a list of every matching file (long), which it then passes to the command. You might do better with a loop or with several mv commands, e.g., `mv a* foo && mv b* foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722245/117259) and specific [details on Apple’s site](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201711), an individual folder can contain up to 2.1 billion items.

That said, just because it can hold up to 2.1 billion items doesn’t mean it can maintain performance at that level. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System#Limitations); emphasis is mine:

> The Catalog File, which stores all the file and directory records in a
>   single data structure, results in performance problems when the system
>   allows multitasking, as only one program can write to this structure
>   at a time, **meaning that many programs may be waiting in queue due to
>   one program "hogging" the system. It is also a serious reliability
>   concern, as damage to this file can destroy the entire file system.**

So performance is naturally degraded thanks to the fact the catalog file can only be used by one program at a time. And if the directory grows in size, the risk/degradation caused by that issue will only escalate; more files means more of a chance for programs to access files in that one directory. Further [confirmation of that idea here](http://www.nobius.org/~dbg/practical-file-system-design.pdf); again emphasis is mine:

> The catalog file is a complicated structure. Because it keeps all file
>   and directory information, it forces serialization of the file
>   system—not an ideal situation when there are a large number of threads
>   wanting to perform file I/O. **In HFS, any operation that creates a file
>   or modifies a file in any way has to lock the catalog file, which
>   prevents other threads from even read-only access to the catalog
>   file. Access to the catalog file must be single- writer/multireader.**

Comment: Thanks so much. I understand the access to the catalog file will be the bottleneck and it can cause serious performance problem especially for multitasking.

Comment: Yes, definitely I am voting your answer and check it off. Again, thanks so much.

Comment: The [Wikipedia sections you cite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System) are talking about scalability limits per filesystem, not per directory: there is only one Catalog File per filesystem and all access must serialize on that. It's fairly irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:** Well, if you're reading 100,000 files, I might expect the script to be slow.

**Long Answer:** To answer this question more thoroughly, you have to look at the file system on a Mac. Macs use the HFS+ ([Hierarchical File System Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)), which is a modern file system that has limitations, but only in extreme situations.

From my experience, it’s a lot like a Linux EXT journaling file system. It supports mounting directories, UNIX-like permissions, etc. It addressed files in a 32-bit format, making the maximum number of files that can be stored in a volume 4,294,967,295, according to [this](http://www.linux.org/threads/hierarchical-file-system-plus-hfs.4493/) source.

The file system starts to break with files bigger than 8 EB on modern systems and up to 2.1 billion files and folders in one location as outlined [here](http://ntfs.com/hfs.htm).

*Given the way the HFS+—or really any file system is setup for that matter—having a lot of files in a folder should not do anything 'weird'.*

Honestly, I don’t think there would be a performance improvement distributing the files across a more complex folder hierarchy. Actually, this technique might be less efficient because your script would have to make calls to change directories mid-process.

Comment: Right. I thought about changing directory hierarchy but it causes more complicated algorithm and I suspect that much performance improvement. Thanks for the answer. I currently have 200,000 files in the directory and might have 1,000,000 at the end. I hope it works fine without that bad performance.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for the advice. I have been thinking about restructuring because I might add some more files. Thanks.